# Bounds on Laplace Transforms

Tags: analysis

Mathematician on this site claims that it's easy to show that for real f in strip [a,b], magnitude of Laplace Transform of f is bounded below by a/s and above by b/s. Can I see the simple demonstration? I would settle for a hint. (I claim an important result would follow from truth of this claim, and I will be happy to publish it here, but I require the result above to go forward.)

Comment: if $|f(t)| < C$ then $|\int_a^b f(t) e^{-st} dt| < \int_a^b C |e^{-st}| dt = \int_a^b C e^{-Re(s)t} dt  = C\frac{e^{-a \ Re(s)}-e^{-b \ Re(s)}}{Re(s)}$

Answer (score 0):

It's not true: take f(x) = 1 + sin(x) and s = delta +i, where delta is a small real number and i = sqrt(-1) as usual. So there won't be a simple demonstration.